# Building programs on multiple platforms?

Tags: c++, linux, windows

I often build programs in c++ and compile them on my own PC.  I'm currently using operating system win xp.

If I want to build copies of my program which will run on linux, other versions of windows etc is there a way of doing this without purchasing those operating systems?  For example, you can get Cygwin to run windows applications on linux. If I had something like that installed could I compile windows products on linux and use them on another windows machine (same bit size)?

Or, do I have to buy the operating system every time?
I'm looking for the most cost effective way of doing this as to build all the libraries I need etc takes allot of time and I'm only using one operating system.  How do others get around this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Use VMWare and appropriate images. It's freely available.

Comment: Most linux distros are free.

Comment: To correct one thing: cygwin is used to run unix/linux code on Windows, Wine is there for running Windows applications on Unix. Cygwin needs to compile your code to binary, Wine not (it takes the original binary)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ VMWare is not free. Windows images are not free as well. Only linux images are free.

Comment: @Dani VMWare is free for non-commercial use (I've got an installation here), also there are free linux images (e.g. for Suse Linux, Ubuntu, etc.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use cross compilers for creating the binaries. A cross compiler enables you to compile code on one architecture for a different architecture, for example a binary for an Android smartphone on Windows. But the output should be tested on the relevant platform, so you still need to "buy" the operating systems because otherwise you can not do your testing.

If you don't want to spend the money you could reinstall evaluation versions in a virtual machine. Microsoft offers evaluation versions of their operating system, but you will have to reinstall after they expire (which will be after 30 to 90 days, sometimes more).
The advantage of a virtual machine is that the hard drive of the virtual pc is simulated in a bunch of files stored on your regular drive. So you need not invest in several hard drives, just plan for 20 - 60 gb per operating system.

Comment: Snapshots will save the hassle of reinstalling :)

Comment: @Jite Microsoft recommends to take snapshots in order to keep their evaluation version running for ever ?

Comment: MS actually recommend you to do this, so I'm sure its not that big of an issue, the background image which comes with the OS tells how to do it. :)

Comment: Hey everyone.. This is great advice, really.  I will look at some of the valuation versions on a separate hard drive with a multiple hard drive slot.   Maybe that's the best way forward.                         One thing I'm not sure I understand is cross-compilers?  How does this work?  You are all right, linux is free and I don't need massive partitions to do what I want to do.  I'll could just build the libraries and install on each partition.  Also.. will look at Snapshots as suggested.  Will save allot of time.  If anyone has any other useful suggestions please let me know.

Comment: Thanks Marged.  It's been bugging me for a while :)